# how to fix broken snaps

Tags: snap, zfs

I have a zfs on root which was upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10
I made a mitake and deleted the zfs pool /var/snap.
I restored it from my 20.04 backup. Now all my snaps are broken. Is there a way to fix that.
Reinstall a snap does not fix the issue.

Comment: How are the snaps broken? Can you expand on this?

Comment: I upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10.  20.10 got corrupt, because I cleaned too many snapshots using the -R option. It was not even bootable. I restored 20.04 from backup snapshots. Now all the snaps are broken. Deleting and reinstalling does not fix.